# Condition variables being send back and forth

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, condition-variable

I have a program that I want to be able to go between different thread. In this example I am just trying to print stuff from a string, and stuff from another string just to see that I am being sent between two threads. I am unable to do this with my code because it hangs up. Ideally I want to work with multiple signals and be able to go back and forth. I have spent about four hours on this and I just can't get it to work, I am thinking that just using global variables would be much more simple and then I would only have to work with a mutex instead of a condition variable, or even no mutex at all.

I just can't get these fickle mutex and condition variable to behave as expected.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

char word1[10] = "Hello";
char word2[10] = "world";

pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;  // mutual exclusion lock for prod
//pthread_mutex_t mutexSigalProd = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
//pthread_cond_t signalToProd = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t addToQ = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;


void * prod(void *arg) { printf("Entering prod \n");
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    int i = 0;

    while (i < 10) {
        printf("PROD adding line: %c \t", word1[i]);
        i++;
        if (i % 2 == 0)
        {
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
            pthread_cond_signal(&addToQ);
            pthread_cond_wait(&addToQ, &mutex);
        }
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}


void * con(void *arg) 
{
    printf("Entering con \n");
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    //pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    pthread_cond_wait(&addToQ, &mutex);
    int i = 0;

    while (i < 10) 
    {
        printf ("CON adding line: %c \t", word2[i]);
        i++;
        if (i % 2 != 0)
        {
            //pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
            pthread_cond_signal(&addToQ);
            pthread_cond_wait(&addToQ, &mutex);
        }
    }

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t threadp1;        // Thread objects
    pthread_t threadp2;
    pthread_t threadc1;

    pthread_create(&threadp1, NULL, prod, NULL);  // start first producer thread
    //pthread_create(&threadp2, NULL, con1, NULL); // start second producer thread
    pthread_create(&threadc1, NULL, con,  NULL); // start consumer thread
    pthread_exit(NULL);              // main thread quits
}
```

Comment: Related: You know you're main thread is creating threads, then simply exiting, right? You're not joining the spawned threads whatsoever. That isn't going to end well. Perhaps a `pthread_join` (or three) may be in order. From what I can see you need a better understanding of how condition variables are used. Don't try to use them to hold "state". Use them to signal a change in predicate data that *you* own and is protected by the associated mutex in the cv/mtx pair. Condition variables are for *signalling*; not for holding predicate info.

Comment: @WhozCraig I don't understand why they need to be joined so I didn't. Anyways I think I have problems besides that. I am not trying to use them to hold state I am trying to use them to control flow of my program.

Comment: @WhozCraig I fixed that and it still doesn't work.

Comment: But you *are* inferring state, whether you realize it or not. Pthreads are not something you generally throw at the wall and hope something sticks. they're meticulous, and shared-predicate eval/modification is not necessarily intuitive. For example, you `con` thread is waiting on a condition variable for... what to change exactly? The only predicate begin checked is a local var that no one else can modify. I *think* I understand what your code *wants* to do. I'll see if I can tailor it to actually do it in an answer, unless someone else beats me to it.

Comment: For my own clarity, is the hope from this that each thread dumps *one* char, then waits for the other to dump *one* char, alternating until one/both reach their respective EOS ? I.e. "Hello" and "World" will produce "HWeolrllod" ?

Comment: @WhozCraig I am just trying to learn threads so I can add 2 items to a queue, them have con remove them, then add 2 more in prod. I was trying to build up to that point by learing cond variables but I can't figure them out. Ideally prod would add to a queue[2] H and then e, con would read and remove H and e and add to another queue, and then prod would add l l and then con would remove them, then prod would add o, see that the string is empty and then con would remove o and exit.

Comment: Sry. I'm trying to find a decent reference on how to use cond-vars and mutexes that wasn't written by *me*. Fundamentally they're all about proper maintenance of the *predicate data* (which is honestly the biggest hurdle for people to get over when using them). In the most simple of terms, the mutex protects access to modify *and* evaluate the external predicate state. The cvar is simply the means to signal threads waiting for changes in the predicate state. I'll keep hunting, but I may just end up posting a related example here.

Comment: Ok, a *very* simple single-producer, multi-consumer example [**can be seen here**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aa44226a1c527fb8). I tried to comment it as liberally as I could. I hope it helps. There a era *ton* of pthread questions on SO that have lots of good answers, so hopefully that helps as well. Best of luck.

Comment: Thank you I will work through it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The race condition in your code is:

Prod sends a signal without checking whether Con is waiting for it. If Con is not yet waiting for the signal, then the signal has no effect (from the man page - "The pthread_cond_broadcast() and pthread_cond_signal() functions shall have no effect if there are no threads currently blocked on cond.").

And then you have both Con and Prod wait for each other. Hence the deadlock.

See if the following code works:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sched.h>

char word1[10] = "Hello";
char word2[10] = "world";
int con_started = 0;

pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;  // mutual exclusion lock for prod
pthread_cond_t addToQ = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

void * prod(void *arg) {
    printf("PROD: Entering prod \n");
    fflush(stdout);
    int i = 0;
    int j = 1;
    while (i < 5) {
        printf("PROD adding line: %c \n", word1[i]);
        fflush(stdout);
        i++;
        if (i % 2 == 0)
        {
            pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
            while(!con_started)
            {
                pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
                sched_yield();
                printf("PROD: Waiting for CON to wait.\n");
                fflush(stdout);
                pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
            }
            printf("PROD: Sending signal %d\n\n", j);
            fflush(stdout);
            pthread_cond_signal(&addToQ);
            printf("PROD: Will wait now \n\n");
            fflush(stdout);
            pthread_cond_wait(&addToQ, &mutex);
            printf("PROD received signal %d\n\n", j);
            fflush(stdout);
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
            j++;
        }
    }
    sched_yield();
    sleep(1);
    printf("PROD: Sending signal %d\n\n", j);
    fflush(stdout);
    pthread_cond_signal(&addToQ);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}


void * con(void *arg)
{
    int i = 0;
    int j=1;
    printf("CON: Entering con \n");
    fflush(stdout);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    con_started = 1;
    printf("CON: Will wait now\n \n");
    fflush(stdout);
    pthread_cond_wait(&addToQ, &mutex);
    printf("CON received first signal\n\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    while (i < 5)
    {
        printf ("CON adding line: %c \n", word2[i]);
        fflush(stdout);
        if (i % 2 != 0)
        {
            //pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
            printf("CON: Sending signal %d\n\n", j);
            fflush(stdout);
            pthread_cond_signal(&addToQ);
            j++;
            printf("CON: Will wait now \n\n");
            fflush(stdout);
            pthread_cond_wait(&addToQ, &mutex);
            printf("CON received signal %d\n\n", j);
            fflush(stdout);
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
        }
        i++;
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t threadp1;        // Thread objects
    pthread_t threadc1;
    pthread_create(&threadp1, NULL, prod, NULL);  // start first producer thread
    pthread_create(&threadc1, NULL, con,  NULL); // start consumer thread
    pthread_join(threadp1, NULL);
    printf("MAIN: threadp1 completed.\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    pthread_join(threadc1, NULL);
    printf("MAIN: threadc1 completed.\n");
    fflush(stdout);
}
```